# Leetcode 1044. Longest Duplicate Substring (small question in terms of modulus)

Tags: java, math, hash, modulus, rabin-karp

I was solving [Leetcode 1044](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-duplicate-substring/) and the answer is using binary search and rolling hash. Basically use binary search to select a length and then do a search for duplicate string of that length. Here rolling hash comes into play to save space (instead of using a set to store all substring, we store substring's hash). That is the background for the solution.

My question is in terms of the modulus used to prevent overflow. I chose Long.MAX_VALUE which I believe is big enough to handle it but the answer is not correct when I use Long.MAX_VALUE. However, when I use Long.MAX_VALUE / 26 or Math.pow(2, 32), they both work. Sorry I'm pretty bad about modulus and I think I definitely missed some things here. Could anyone shed some light on it? Thanks! The following is my solution:

```
public static long modulus = Long.MAX_VALUE / 26;
public String longestDupSubstring(String S) {
    int n = S.length();
    int l = 1;
    int r = n - 1;
    int index = -1;
    while (l <= r) {
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;
        int temp = findDuplicate(S, m);
        if (temp != -1) {
            index = temp;
            l = m + 1;
        }
        else {
            r = m - 1;
        }
    }
    return index == -1 ? "" : S.substring(index, index + r);
}
private int findDuplicate(String s, int len) {
    Set<Long> set = new HashSet<>();
    long hash = 0;
    long p = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        hash = (hash * 26 + s.charAt(i) - 'a') % modulus;
        p = (p * 26) % modulus;
    }
    set.add(hash);
    
    for (int i = len; i < s.length(); i++) {
        hash = (hash * 26 + (s.charAt(i) - 'a')
                - (s.charAt(i - len) - 'a') * p) % modulus;
        if (hash < 0) {
            hash += modulus;
        }
        if (set.contains(hash)) {
            return i - len + 1;
        }
        set.add(hash);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: What would be the point of `longValue % Long.MAX_VALUE`? Unless `longValue` is *exactly* equal to `Long.MAX_VALUE`, the expression will do ... **nothing**.

Answer (score 0):

26 is not part of the modulus, is part of hashing. If we would separate those in the algorithm, then we might see how it'd work. For modulus usually a large number would simply suffice, does not have to be a `long`:

```
public final class Solution {
    int a = 26;
    int mod = 1 << 29;

    public final String longestDupSubstring(
        final String s
    ) {
        int lo = 1;
        int hi = s.length() - 1;

        while (lo <= hi) {
            int mid = lo + ((hi - lo) >> 1);
            int startIndex = search(s, mid);

            if (startIndex == - 1) {
                hi = mid - 1;
            }

            else {
                lo = -~mid;
            }
        }

        int startIndex = search(s, hi);
        return startIndex == -1 ? "" : s.substring(startIndex, startIndex + hi);
    }

    public final int search(
        final String s,
        final int len
    ) {
        long h = 0;
        long aL = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = (h * a % mod + s.charAt(i)) % mod;
            aL = aL * a % mod;
        }

        HashMap<Long, List<Integer>> visited = new HashMap<>();
        visited.put(h, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        visited.get(h).add(0);

        for (int i = 1; i < -~s.length() - len; i++) {
            h = ((h * a % mod - s.charAt(i - 1) * aL % mod + mod) % mod + s.charAt(i + len - 1)) % mod;

            if (visited.containsKey(h)) {
                for (int start : visited.get(h)) {
                    if (s.substring(start, start + len).equals(s.substring(i, i + len))) {
                        return i;
                    }
                }

            } else {
                visited.put(h, new ArrayList<Integer>());
            }

            visited.get(h).add(i);
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```